# React Native Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/functionbut got: undefined. But where?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am the first person to have this error when putting an overlay in my code

```
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(true);
  return (
    
    <View>
        <Button
          buttonStyle="moreBtn"
          title="aaa"
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })
          }
        />
         <Overlay>
          <Text>Hello from verlay!</Text>
        </Overlay> 
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={true}
          visible={modal}
          style={styles.modal}
          onPress={() => {
            setModal(false)
          }}
        >
          <View style={{height:500}}>
          <Text>aaaaa</Text>
          <Button onPress={() => {
            setModal(false)
          }}>Bouton</Button>
          </View>
        </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};
```

When I put overlay component JSX inside my render function, i Have this error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Why ?

I edited my post to add my following imports at the top of the file.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, FlatList, ScrollView, Modal } from 'react-native';
import Overlay from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
```

The "HomeScreen" is inside an "App" BottomTabNavigator element

```
export default App;
```

Comment: Probably an issue with importing something, as the error message says. Can you show us this file's imports, and the export for any custom components?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post

Comment: `import Overlay from 'react-native';` That's not going to work. Did you mean `import { Overlay } from 'react-native-elements';`?

Answer (score 2):

You are importing Overlay wrongly react-native doesn't have an Overlay component, you can use Overlay from `react-native-elements`

change

```
import Overlay from 'react-native';
```

to

```
import { Overlay } from 'react-native-elements';
```

check this:https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/overlay.html

Answer (score 1):

Even though @user12129132 has already answered the question here, I'm leaving this as an answer for future finders with a little more information.

First, this error, at least as far as I know, ALWAYS means you imported something incorrectly. In the case you are importing your own component/function you may have exported it incorrectly.

For this specific example you messed up the import 2 times.

First: Overlay is not a part of react-native, so that fails.

Second: Overlay is not the default export of the package it comes from.

Imports take the following form: `import DefaultExport, { NamedExport1, NamedExport2 ...} from 'package-name/file-path';

When looking at errors like this, first check your exports, if it is your own file you are importing from, and then check your import to make sure it fits the above format, frequently you swapped the named export and default export around. Sometimes the actual error is in the file you imported, and IT has a broken import - those can be fun to trace down and fix.

Simple mistake to make, easy to fix once you learn this.

So, given the above information, your import should look like this:
`import { Overlay } from 'react-native-elements';`

Comment: Thanks for this. I almost lost my mind